# How many Annunaki were living on Earth at the peak of their time?

Tags: mesopotamia, anunnaki

The Anunnaki were a group of deities in ancient Mesopotamian culture.

How many of them were there at the peak time (which we know about)?

For example on [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anunnaki#Mythology) we can read:

> In the Epic of Creation, it is said that there are 300 lgigu of heaven.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on excavation and digs we have currently found over 560 deities. However scientist believe that there could be as many as 750.

According to Bottéro's book titled: *Religion in Ancient Mesopotamia*

> A Sumerian list of around 560 deities that did this was uncovered at
>   Fâra and Tell Abû Ṣalābīkh and dated to circa 2600 BCE, ranking five
>   primary deities as being of particular importance.

Comment: +1, though I (mis)read your first sentence at first as "they have excavated 560 gods so far" which made me wonder if the Mesopotamians actually buried their dead gods.