# What is the difference between Igigi and Anunnaki deities?

Tags: comparative, sumerian, anunnaki

On Anunnaki Wikipedia page we can read:

> Their relation to the group of gods known as the Igigi is unclear – at times the names are used synonymously but in the Atra-Hasis flood myth the Igigi are the sixth generation of the gods who have to work for the Anunnaki, rebelling after 40 days and replaced by the creation of humans.

Further down:

> Jeremy Black and Anthony Green offer a slightly different perspective on the Igigi and the Anunnaki, writing that "lgigu or Igigi is a term introduced in the Old Babylonian Period as a name for the (ten) "great gods".
>
> In the Epic of Creation, it is said that there are 300 lgigu of heaven.

In this [answer](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/a/221/51) we can read that scientists believe that there could be as many as 750 Anunnaki.

Therefore, what is the difference between Igigi and Anunnaki, can anybody elaborate that?

Were they different group of deities or Igigi were just the lower class of Anunnaki?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I remember well, they are 2 **different classes** of gods.

In this myth of the creation of the Human (saga of Atrahasis), It is said that Anunnaki deities were ruling in the heaven, it comes from the sumerian *A-nun-na(k) : which comes from An (Master of the Universe and Lord of the Creation)*.

In the Atra-Hasis (flood myth), we can read that Igigi deities (or Igigu) were deities from the Earth, who were supposed to give presents to Anunnaki deities, by working, etc.

But one day, they revolt, and it ends up by the creation of the Human race, in order to do the work of the Igigi.

So at this time, Anunnaki are superior gods and Igigi inferior gods, but they are in the heaven.

On the myth of the creation of Babylon (Enuma Elish), the god Marduk becomes the leader of the Gods (successor of Enlil), and decide they will be 600 gods, Igigi in the sky and Anunnaki on the Earth.

In the myth of Innana (descent in the hell), Anunnaki are described as judge of the hell and they are 71.

That is all I know from it, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

When taking all known narratives together. The Igig were/are a class of the Anunnaki. I look at it like the divide between royalty and commoners of Europe .

Inferences being the Igigi/Annunaki came to earth/mars together. Note in Sitchin's translation. It states the Anunnaki outlawed slavery at some point in their distant past.

Thinking the Igigi were the descendants of the slave class in their distant past. No reason to think their developing/evolving would not take on some physical differences amongst themselves.

Seems to reason that over time they ended up with a relationship similar to what Britain has had the last 200 years. Using the military as a way to explain. 
Everyone in Britain can enlist. But to be an officer. The commoner moves up the ranks either by your service time, education or some sort of combination. As a royal, You are automatically an admiral.    Just some thoughts.