# Are the Anunnaki mentioned in the Bible?

Tags: comparative, sumerian, anunnaki, bible

The following Bible passages mention “*Anakim*” and “*Anak*”:

- Num 13:22; 13:28; 13:33
- Deut 1:28; 2:10-11; 2:21, 9:2
- Josh 11:21-22; 14:12; 14:15; 15:13-14; 21:11
- Judg 1:20.

They sound similar.

Is there any known connection between the biblical *Anakim*/*Anak* entities and the Sumerian Anunnaki gods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How could they be related ? Anakim just means "*sons of Anak*".
It is just a race of giants, and there is nothing giving them godlike power or something.

Anunnaki, as I explained in [another post](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/311/what-is-the-difference-between-igigi-and-anunnaki-deities/1739#1739), means sons of An. While the terminology is the same, there is nothing in common between those 2 words.

EDIT : The sumerian language is apparently an language isolate. So it is just a coincidence.

More than that, in the International Standard Bible Encyclopedia, an hypothesis linked this word with a [goddess from the eastern cultural block](https://www.studylight.org/encyclopedias/isb/view.cgi?n=499.), but it is not linked to a semitic deity. Still, I don't see any link with the sumerian gods.

Comment: The problem being that "[An(u)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anu)" had the same name in Akkadian, which is a Semitic language.  Sumerian and Akkadian co-existed for several centuries at least.  So any conclusions about phonetic coincidence, while stll highly likely, can't be based on Sumerian being a language isolate.

Answer (score 3):

Abraham came from Sumer. His birth place was "Ur of the Chaldees", namely UR KAŠDIM (אוּר כַּשְׂדִּים). This is explicitly stated in Genesis 11:28:

> "And died Haran before the face of Terah his father in the land of his
> birth in **UR OF THE CHALDEANS.**"

> הָרָ֔ן עַל־ פְּנֵ֖י תֶּ֣רַח אָבִ֑יו בְּאֶ֥רֶץ מוֹלַדְתּ֖וֹ בְּא֥וּר כַּשְׂדִּֽים׃

> hā-rān,   ‘al-pə-nê te-raḥ ’ā-ḇîw bə-’e-reṣ mō-w-laḏ-tōw bə-**’ŪR KAŚ-DÎM.**

Haran was Abraham's brother and Terah their father. So there will absolutely be linguistic and esoteric interconnections with Hebrew, Akkadian, Assyrian. You don't share a border and common history without retaining some linguistic elements.

"Language Isolate" just means they (Sumerologists) haven't yet figured out how Sumerian relates to the surrounding languages.

Answer (score 2):

Anunnaki - Gods of Sumeria Or fallen Angels??

I found it very interesting that the earliest civilisation known to us in the historical records, the Sumerians, have a religion that talks of these Anunnaki coming down from heaven and teaching them all wonders of things.

I found a correlation between fallen angels and the Anunnaki. It's rather coincidental that our faith teaches of a war that ended in one third of the angels falling to earth, whilst in our history we have our first civilisation who are taught by Gods who "came" from the heavens. Perhaps they did not so much come from heaven as they where kicked out.

Now after reading numbers(13: 28) in the scripture I came across the descendants of Anak who where described as giants.  The word Anak  itself  sounded eerily similar to the Anunnaki which I had recently been studying and so it got me thinking.

After further reading I came across Numbers 13:33 (In parenthesis though of course) in which I was informed that the Anakites come from the nephilim! So, if we take this all together we can see that;

We have the war of heaven a long time ago and then we also have beings coming from the sky to be worshipped by the Sumerians as Gods; also a long time ago. We know the Sumerians called these Gods anunnaki. Is it such a stretch to theorise that the fallen angels of our faith are the "so called Gods" coming to the Sumerians? We know God's hate for Babylon and Babylon is really just another form of the Sumerian culture which came after Sumaria in the same location.

Then we read in the Bible of a people descendant from anuk who are giant and strong who come from the nephilim: Numbers 13:32.

Now of course I don't have to mention that the nephilim are also called the sons of God, and the sons of God is another word for angels.

So it is clear that not only in language is their a similarity between the word anak or anakites and the anunnaki. But also in the relationship between the Anakites being descendants of nephelim and the anakites being heavenly beings.

I think it's probably that like in the Bible the anakites are descendent from angels, so to are the anunnaki angels who have fallen from heaven.

Interesting facts. The Anunnaki interestingly has been said to mean princely offspring. The devil is known as the prince of the sky.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the fact that there is no such thing as an Annunaki until coined by Sitchin who had no idea what he was talking about. The word Annunaki can't even be found in the original text.

Annunaki= Anakim = Sons of Anak in the Old Testament
The correlation is found in the timeline: the fact that Hebrews and Sumerians Co-existed. The Old Testament is documenting the times just like
the epic of Gilgamesh, the legend of Atrahasis, the book of Jasher, the book of Job, other extra Biblical texts, the 7 tablets of creation and the books of Enoch.

All coming from the same time period. 3000-1800 B.C. (pre flood times-1800 B.C.E.). Note the epic of Gilgamesh refers to a time when Noah was 366 years old and During Egypt's Second Dynasty.(234 years before the flood).
They all (Sumerian, Assyrian, Babylonian, Hebrew, Egyptian, Akkadian, etc) coexisted in trade, war, god worship, etc.
Just look at the timeline.

And it is easy to see that they are all referring to the same infamous nephilim.
Finally the vowels never determined the meaning of a word or a name but rather the consonants. Anunnaki= Anak.